# How to create log file from my bash script

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, tee

How can I make a log file from my bash script?

I'm leaving the script without the options, all I want to know is how I can register the script being used and make a separate `.log` file.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trash=~/TRASH
if [ ! -e $trash ]; then
  mkdir $trash
elif [ ! -d $trash ]; then
  echo "$0: error: $trash is not a directory"; exit 1
fi

while getopts "hr:t:s:u:" options; do
case $options in

#ALL THE OPTIONS AREN'T HERE FOR THE PURPOSE OF KEEPING IT SHORTER

shift $((OPTIND-1))

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  if [ ! -e $1 ]; then
    echo "$0: error: tried to delete file that does not exist: $1"
    shift
    continue
  fi
  tarname="$1.tar"
  tar -cf "$tarname" "$1"
  mv "$tarname" $trash
  rm -rf "$1"
  shift
done
```

Comment: this is going to come down to what you wish to accomplish; the script generates some output (via `echo` calls) ... should the output go to **both** stdout (eg, you want to see the messages on your terminal) **and** to a log file?  for repeated calls do you want to **append** to the previous log, **overwrite** the previous log (thus keeping the output from just the last run) or write the output to a **new** log each time the script runs?  do you want to capture stderr to the log file, too?

Comment: also, do you wish to write the log to a specific directory (eg, `~/logs`) as opposed to writing to whatever directory you happen to be sitting in when you run the script (ie, this could leave your log file(s) spread throughout the filesystem ... making it hard to find the log file you want ... and leaving you with a (minor) headache when it comes to cleaning up 'old' log files); also consider how you plan to manage 'old' log files (or 'old' entries in a single log file) ... over time you'll probably want to prune 'old' log entries/files (separate script running under cron?)

Comment: Yes, the objective is to have the output come out both on the terminal and in the log file, and simply appending to the log file not overwriting it. Yes I did want stderr captured aswell. By doing `#!/bin/bash
(
  blah code
) > file.log` the output only comes to the log and that's one of the issues I was having

Comment: Right I'm aware but since this is for a school project it doesn't really matter in the end so the directory doesn't matter and neither does keeping track of the logs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display stdout and stderr to both the console and the log, and to append to the log, perhaps something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
  blah code
) 2>&1 | tee -a file.log
```

Where:

- `2>&1` - redirect stderr to stdout
- `| tee -a file.log` - send stdout to console but also 'tee' up a copy to be `-a`ppended to `file.log`

---

---

Working example:

```
$ cat blah
(
echo "hello"                 # will print to stdout
dirxys                       # will send message to stderr
) 2>&1 | tee -a blah.log

# both stdout/stderr show up on console:

$ blah
hello
./blah: line 3: dirxys: command not found

# both stdout/stderr also show up in log:

$ cat blah.log
hello
./blah: line 3: dirxys: command not found
```

Comment: Perfect, works just as intended thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

One way...

```
#!/bin/bash
(
  blah code
) > file.log
```

Comment: I had already tried that, however the log file is always empty

Comment: Same thing, after I use it the log is still empty

Comment: It does log the errors, but when I run the script without errors it doesn't log anything

Comment: And how can I keep adding to the log instead of just replacing the file? because by doing that it just adds to the log once and when I use it again it's wiped

Comment: >> instead of >

Comment: I just realized this redirects the entire output, and some output I want to come in the terminal, such as the help option, how can I create the log and still do this at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Just call the script and redirect its output:

```
./script.sh > script.log
```

Comment: I put that in the end of the script and when I run it it says permission denied from that line

Comment: Then perhaps the log file already exists, but is owned by another user.

Comment: How can the log file exist if I just wrote the script and I'm on a VM with just 1 user?

Comment: Are you perhaps operating in a folder that is owned by root or trying to write to a folder that is owned by root?

Answer (score 0):

late answer

this with parenthesis dont work for sh files of type
wget that ...
wget that ...
wget that ...

Solution:
`./script.sh 2>&1 | tee -a file.log`